# Mac M1 Homebrew Perl Carton Net::SSLeay is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way

Tags: perl, openssl, homebrew, apple-m1

I'm trying to install Net::SSLeay with Carton.
The installation fails with this message

```
Configuring Net-SSLeay-1.90 Running Makefile.PL Do you want to run external tests? 
These tests *will* *fail* if you do not have network connectivity. [n] n 
*** Found LibreSSL-2.8.3 installed in /usr 
*** Be sure to use the same compiler and options to compile your OpenSSL, perl, and Net::SSLeay. Mixing and matching compilers is not supported. 
Checking if your kit is complete... Looks good 
WARNING: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.32.1_1/bin/perl is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way -> N/A
```

I've tried this with system perl, brew perl and multiple perlbrew perls.
Google came up with a temp solution to build homebrew using x86_64 architecture.
This did work for the libcrypto error, but gave me a whole different set of issues including mysql not running anymore.

Other "solutions" that I've tried are symlinking libssl & libcrypto as suggested by numerous other posts, all sadly without success.

Any ideas  how to fix this or work around this without having to reinstall all brew packages as  x86_64 ?

### Quick Workaround

If you are looking for a quick workaround follow these steps.

1. Run `carton bundle` to create a vendor cache directory.
2. Go to cached tarball 'cache/authors/id/C/CH/CHRISN/' and unpack `tar -xvzf Net-SSLeay-1.90.tar.gz`
3. Edit Makefile.PL, change `my $prefix = find_openssl_prefix();` to
   `my $prefix = '/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1';` ** adjust to your openssl location.
4. Save and create new tarball `tar -czvf Net-SSLeay-1.90.tar.gz Net-SSLeay-1.90`
5. Run `carton install --cached` to use the altered version

Hope this helps anyone in search of workaround

Comment: *"perl is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way..."* I can reproduce this on my MacBook Air, not sure what is going yet but the debugger shows that the error occurs in a call to `DynaLoader::dl_load_file("/usr/lib/libssl.dylib", 0 );` at [line 178](https://metacpan.org/source/BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.60/lib%2FExtUtils%2FLiblist%2FKid.pm#L178) in `ExtUtils::Liblist::Kid`

Comment: Added [bug report](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/18700)

Comment: I'v added a workaround to the OP

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can solve this in two steps:

- upgrade [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](https://metacpan.org/release/ExtUtils-MakeMaker) to at least version 7.58 (e.g. `cpanm ExtUtils::MakeMaker`)
- install `openssl` via [macports](https://www.macports.org/) (`sudo port install openssl`) or [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) (`brew install --cask openssl`)

Answer (score 5):

After the Monterey update this broke again also on the x86_64 architecture, but just symlinking your latest openssl (where ever it is, depending how you have installed it) seemed to fix this. Example:

```
$ export OPENSSL_PREFIX=[find your openssl installation]
$ sudo ln -s $OPENSSL_PREFIX/lib/libssl.dylib /usr/local/lib/
$ sudo ln -s $OPENSSL_PREFIX/lib/libcrypto.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```

Answer (score 4):

Better workaround:

I entered `export OPENSSL_PREFIX=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1` in my shell and then ran `cpan`. I checked the code in `Makefile.PL` and the first thing the function `find_openssl_prefix` does is to check the `OPENSSL_PREFIX` environment variable. If it is set, then it the function will return its contents.

Add the variable to your .profile, .cshrc, .bashrc, .zshrc, or whatever rc file your shell uses and you never have to worry about it again!!

Comment: Just a note to those of you who were confused like I was the @ doesn't mean a literal @ in the directory path so don't worry if that path doesn't exist on your system.

Comment: For me this wasn't enough, I had to create 2 symlinks in `/usr/local/lib` as described in https://github.com/radiator-software/p5-net-ssleay/issues/268#issuecomment-817109697 before it worked.  This is on Apple M1, macOS Monterey.